# Can a mounted Summoner use Mounted Combat to avoid attacks to their Eidolon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, mounted-combat, summoner, eidolon

I've been tangling with a mounted Summoner build for a while, and I'm having trouble parsing feats that the Summoner herself can take and how they affect an Eidolon being used as a mount.

My main question is, can the Summoner use the Ride check provided by the Mounted Combat feat to avoid an attack on their Eidolon? Mounted Combat reads:

> Once per round when your mount is hit in combat, you may attempt a Ride check (as an immediate action) to negate the hit. The hit is negated if your Ride check result is greater than the opponent’s attack roll.

The Mount evolution is simply described with

> An eidolon is properly skilled and formed to serve as a combat-trained mount. [size restriction text omitted]

So my understanding of this situation is that, as per having the Mount evolution, the eidolon counts as a mount, and thus qualifies the Summoner to be able to protect them using the Ride check offered by Mounted Combat. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you can

When the [Eidolon Mount](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/eidolon-mount-combat/) evolution says that it serves *as* a mount, all abilities and rules that affect mounts can now affect your eidolon.

> serve as a combat-trained mount

This includes all uses of the [Ride](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/ride) skill. And... that's it, there isn't much use of saying that your eidolon serves as a combat-trained mount other than allowing you to use the Ride skill in combat. There is no other special benefit of that rule. So, it wouldn't make a lot of sense if the skill wasn't allowed to be used on your eidolon.